# How to start WATCH command in background for php script

Tags: ubuntu, php

I need to start a php proccess `php /srv/devde/current/artisan doing_decisions` but monitored with `watch` command. How can I start it?

I have been trying to start like this, but failed:

```
nohup watch -n0 php /srv/devde/current/artisan doing_decisions
```

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 server.

Comment: I don't think `watch` is the right thing here. My understanding of the command is it will *repeatedly* execute (and display the results, which makes `nohup` kinda odd too), with a minimum `-n` value of `0.1` seconds in between executions. If you want to keep a long-running process going, use something like Supervisor.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for the explanation. It is was I needed, I think you can post it as an answer, because it solve my problem, maybe others will also has the same issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `watch` is the right thing here. My understanding of the command is it will repeatedly execute (and display the results, which makes `nohup` kinda odd too), with a minimum `-n` value of `0.1` seconds in between executions.

If you want to keep a long-running process going, use something like Supervisor. Laravel has [instructions on setting up Supervisor for the queueing system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#supervisor-configuration), which you can easily adapt to your command.